# search several web sites using C#

Tags: c#, search, web-crawler

Can I use C# to auto search websites, then return the search results?

Is there a web crawler that would do the same thing if I give it a top domain (ex: I tell it find the word "funny" on stackoverflow.com, and it would tell me all the times "funny" appeared)?

These web sites allow searching via their search bar.

Do I need the web sites cooperation to automate searches?

NOTE: I only plan to be doing about one or two searches a day, so I doubt I'll be blocked, or asked to authenticate myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your planning on crawling through an entire website to count words like that if you dont cache it you will get blocked, youll be requesting every page of the website essentially. Perhaps consider integrating google domain search's instead?

Here is a link to googles page detailing how to interface with c#

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/client-cs.html

**EDIT:** Sorry that wasn't quite right : http://gsalib.codeplex.com/

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2165-how-to-search-google-and-bing-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

`...web sites allow searching via their search bar ... Can I use C# to auto search websites, then return the search results?`

Yes, if the website provides a URL where the search-term is provided as a query-string argument to a URL.

```
          http://yourTargetDomain?searchterm=foo
```

But unless the website has specifically designed the search results from that URL to be structured data, the website won't "tell [you] all the times 'funny' appeared" but will send you back a search response that is suitable for a browser to display, so you would have to parse the results out of this stream of HTML.

For example:

http://philadelphia.craigslist.org/search/tls?query=ladder&srchType=A&minAsk=&maxAsk=

Comment: If it was that simple I wouldn't need help.

The site assigns a search ID ex. "/SearchResults.aspx?searchID=00865caa-ed5c-46a1-b850-0450f102dda5&page=0&set=0&pageSize=100"

However the page I want to get to is just a standard webpage. ex: "[lots of other non-changing stuff]RecID=5358254"

Comment: @wizlog: I think you have misunderstood me. I was not suggesting it is simple; rather I was showing you that it is indeed not as simple as you hoped it might be; the result of such a URL with search-term appended to the query string is a stream of HTML markup, not a mere list of occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into building an RSS aggregator. RSS is standardized, so that's probably the most reliable way to collect search results from various sources.

**EDIT**: For sites that don't support RSS

For the sites that don't support RSS, you can look into using a screen scraper. Check out this article on The Code Project to get you started:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/weather.aspx

Comment: What if the site doesn't provide an RSS feed?

Comment: You can look into using a screen scraper for sites that don't support RSS.

Comment: Yes, but I'd still need to manually go to each webpage and type in my query, right?  I'll be searching 50 separate sites, that's why I'm looking for a way to make it go faster.

Comment: I believe the article shows how to query the site for results. It's basically just using a WebRequest to read the response stream and parse the results.

Comment: If you maintain a list of the sites to search, you should be able to automate the screen scraping process. You can use some asyncrhonous calls to execute several searches at once to speed things up too.